# ¿Cómo recorrer un elemento mediante su clase?

Tags: jquery

Tengo una matriz de inputs y quiero recorrer de forma vertical cuando se presiona la tecla enter, lo que he intentado no funciona,que es lo que podría estar fallando, dejo el jsfiddle de lo que necesito y de antemano muchas gracias.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").on("keydown", function(e){
     if(e.which === 13){
       $(this).parents().find("input.start1").next().focus();
     }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="start1" value="1.1"></td>
    <td><input class="start2" value="2.1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="start1" value="1.2"></td>
    <td><input class="start2" value="2.2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="start1" value="1.3"></td>
    <td><input class="start2" value="2.3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="start1" value="1.4"></td>
    <td><input class="start2" value="2.4"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="start1" value="1.5"></td>
    <td><input class="start2" value="2.5"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vozsyngz/

Comment: Bienvenido, te sugiero leer [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: ¿recorrerlo? ¿harás la suma de esos elementos?

Comment: prácticamente es sólo para recorrerlos e ir guardando sus valores pero si se pudiera si @ReneLimon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si entendi bien, lo que buscas es recorrer todos los input mientras se va precionando enter. Se logra sabiendo en cual columna estas y si estas en el final de la columna, pues entonces saltar a la siguiente:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  

  $("input").on("keydown", function(e){
     if(e.which === 13){
     
     // verificamos posicion del actual
     var $this = $(this);
     var actualClass = $this.attr("class");
     
     
     if(actualClass == "start1")
     {
       // verificamos si es el ultimo de la primera columna
       if($(".start1:last").is($this))
       {
        // como es el ultimo, saltamos al primer input de la siguiente columna
        $(".start2:first").focus();
       }
       else{
        // no es el ultimo, continuamos
        $(this).closest("tr")
        .next().find("input:first").focus();
       }
     }
     else{
     
        // verificamos si es el ultimo de la primera columna
       
       if($(".start2:last").is($this))
       {
        // como es el ultimo, saltamos al primer input de la siguiente columna
        $(".start1:first").focus();
       }
       else{
        // no es el ultimo, continuamos
        $(this).closest("tr")
        .next().find("input:last").focus();
       }
     }
        
        
        
     }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="start1" value="1.1"></td>
    <td><input class="start2" value="2.1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="start1" value="1.2"></td>
    <td><input class="start2" value="2.2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="start1" value="1.3"></td>
    <td><input class="start2" value="2.3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="start1" value="1.4"></td>
    <td><input class="start2" value="2.4"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="start1" value="1.5"></td>
    <td><input class="start2" value="2.5"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias por tu código amigo Einer, me ha servido de mucho, dejo el código que implementé con tu respuesta

```
$("input").on("keydown", function(e){
    var enter  = 13;
    var mi_clase = $(this).attr('clase');
    if(e.which === enter) {
        if( $(this).val()!=="" ) {
            $(this).closest("tr").next().find("input." + mi_clase).focus();
        }
    }
});
```